# Oracle Group by Based on part of string

Tags: regex, oracle

How to make Group by based on part of string.

Example :

AB-1234

AB 1234

Want to group by based on "AB1234" . Should not consider 3rd character while grouping.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of a regex, `substr` will be faster, try this:

```
group by substr(yourField, 1, 2) || substr(yourField, 4)
```

See a documentation about it: http://psoug.org/definition/substr.htm

If you still want to do a regex it would be:

```
group by regexp_replace(yourField, '([\w]{2})\w(.+)', '\1\2')
```

Comment: Thanks Jorge, can i have regular expression for the same.

Comment: No problem :). Did not understand `can i have regular expression for the same` is this a question?

Comment: Yes, I was trying with Regular Expression but could not  get it. Thanks :)